# VSCode python interactive window: fix nvidia gpu support for tensorflow / pytorch

Tags: python, tensorflow, visual-studio-code, nvidia, python-interactive

I just want to give you the solution for my problem as it took me quite some time to solve it and like always, the solution was very simple.

It also addresses this github issue which was closed without answer: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-jupyter/issues/1697

## Problem

I properly setup the local installation of nvidia driver and tensorflow.

Running this snippet in python shell or .py file in a terminal (external or integrated vscode terminal) resulted in the following output:

```py
# %%
import tensorflow as tf

gpus = tf.config.list_physical_devices('GPU')
print(gpus)hon

# Result: [PhysicalDevice(name='/physical_device:GPU:0', device_type='GPU')]
```

But within python interactive window (jupyter notebook) by clicking -> Run cell,
I just received an empty list [].

## Do you have the same problem?

1. Have a look at the output of the jupyter notebook by:
   Vscode -> Terminal -> Output section -> Change top right to Jupyter and have a look at the error message
   e.g. a library wasn't found
2. Have a look at the environment variable **LD_LIBRARY_PATH** which is used to set paths to c libraries and which is normally set/extended in the .bashrc file during installation of nvidia cuDNN.

In your terminal:

```sh
echo $LD_LIBRARY_PATH
```

In your ipython/jupyter interactive vscode cell

```py
import os
os.environ["LD_LIBRARY_PATH"]
# If you receive a key error, then the variable isn't set
```

They should have the same output, e.g. `/usr/lib/cuda/include:/usr/lib/cuda/lib64:`

3. If they differ or you get an KeyError, then I can help you.
   They differ, because the jupyter notebook is not started as a login shell and therefore does not load the bashrc, also does not have the exported variables.

## Solution

The solution is to create a `.env` file in the python root directory of your project and include this content:

```
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib/cuda/include:/usr/lib/cuda/lib64:
```

Reload the VSCode Window, et voila, it worked without error.

I found the solution in these to links:

- https://github.com/jupyter/notebook/issues/5871 -> Solution for jupyter notebook run externally (not within jupyter notebook)
- https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-jupyter/issues/1467#issuecomment-767914345

Comment: Not really. It shall help others to that have the same problem to get a clue how to solve their issue.

Comment: How can I do it in the windows? And does it work with pytorch too? I have same problem with pytorch but in windows.

Comment: As this is a cuda issue, this should be valid for both tensorflow and pytorch.

Comment: @ArtaAsadi Here is a link to check and set environment variables in windows: https://phoenixnap.com/kb/windows-set-environment-variable